# How to design a WCF service which can support 10,000 simultaneous hits

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am a beginner in WCF and want to take some help in creating a WCF for my project.

I have to create a WCF service which can support 10,000 users simultaneous hits.

The job of the WCF service is to fetch a cached up XML object (we are using Enterprise Lib caching) and return it to the caller.

This WCF service will have to be publicly exposed. So I was thinking that we may have to use basicHttpBinding... I don't know, I may be wrong.

Can anyone please suggest the best way of going ahead with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use reliable messaging
- Don't use sessions
- Don't use transactions
- Don't use Duplex
- Don't use message security
- Use BasicHttpBinding or NetTcpBinding
- if you need security on HTTP, use HTTPS (TCP already implements encryption)

**My personal view**, don't use WCF if you need performance! :) Use ASP NET MVC with JSON message format and if you need security, use HTTPS.